# Full-Bridge DC-DC Converter Transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, magnetics, full-bridge

I try to design a full bridge DC-DC converter (hard switch) and I have some concerns about it's transformer design.

1. As I know its transformer doesn't store energy and it doesn't have an air-gap?
2. If it doesn't have an air gap, that means amount of turns we have in primary will determine the inductance?
3. If amount of turns will determine the inductance, that means there is no specific formula for full bridge transformer primary inductance?
4. If I have 10 turns in primary, I'll have (10^2)xAl inductance and this is my only option. I can increase the inductance with increase in number of turns and can't decrease it since the number of turns formula gives minimum number of turns?

I guess there is no specific inductance formula or calculation for it, I may have 50 or 750 uH... according to number of turns and that's all right?

Comment: The inductance *always* scales with number of turns squared. Air gap or not.

Comment: Of course it can have an air-gap. You implement an air-gap to reduce the effects of core saturation (or use a much bigger core). All real transformers (to some extent) inevitably store energy.

Comment: @tobalt yes it is but, without air-gap only option is changing the number of turns to change the inductance, I mean that.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, as I remember I've read somewhere that it shouldn't have an air-gap. Thanks for correction. Then how can I determine that how much inductance I need on primary? Is there a specific formula or way for it?

Comment: It boils down to what drive voltage you are wanting to apply to it and, whether the magnetization current will cause too much saturation. Think of it just as an inductor with no secondary <-- that's how you evaluate peak magnetization current. Then, using the dimensions of the ferrite core (for instance) you calculate the peak H-field. That then leads on to showing the peak flux density and, if above (say) 200 mT, you either make a bigger gap (with more turns) or choose a bigger core-set.

Comment: Please simulate your design with the transformer ratio you need and vary the primary magnitization inductance? What happens? From here, determine low little inductance you can cope with. This will be the limiting number for your design.

Comment: If it "doesn't store energy", what consequence is the inductance? It's high enough not to matter! If you're worried about having enough turns, that is determined by the flux density -- the magnetization required to reach that flux density, we can ensure is small, by choosing a high \$\mu\$ material (and thus, the inductance high enough).

Answer (score 2):

> *As I know it's transformer doesn't store energy and it doesn't have an
> air-gap right?*

Many transformers have air-gaps (especially if you are trying to use the smallest core-set in your application). If you don't use a gap, on many occasions, you may need to use a bigger core-set.

But, what is an air-gap?...

If you look at various ferrite material data sheets, they'll state a figure for magnetic permeability and, that figure can vary considerably from one material to the next. The reason is that ferrites have a distributed air-gap; it's inherent in the material mix. So, there is always an air-gap and some materials have a bigger distributed air-gap than others.

> *If it doesn't have an air gap, that means amount of turns we have in
> primary will determine the inductance right?*

Whether it has a physical and obvious air-gap or not is irrelevant; the number of turns squared will roughly dictate the amount of inductance. However, if you reduce the effective permeability of the core by using a gap, then the inductance factor (A<sub>L</sub>) will also reduce linearly with the lower permeability hence net inductance lowers for the same number of turns.

> *If amount of turns will determine the inductance, that means there is
> no specific formula for full bridge transformer primary inductance
> right?*

Here's the real nub of the question.

**If the number of turns is too high** then: -

- You may not be able to fit the windings into a particular core-set.
- The leakage inductance could also be too high for decent operation.
- The DC wire resistance may also be too high for efficient operation.

**If the number of turns is too low** then the magnetization current may cause core saturation.

You have a balancing act; you need to choose just enough turns to avoid excessive core saturation.

So, you need to estimate, for a particular number of turns and, a particular core-set, what the H-field will be. You then convert this figure to flux density and aim for roughly (rule of thumb) a peak flux density of circa 200 mT (ferrite materials).

Iterate, iterate...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on inductor and transformer design. It may have some errors, but I don't see them.

https://www.switchcraft.org/learning/2016/12/10/transformer-and-inductor-design

Comment: This is a very unspecific link only answer. Have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/200687

Comment: This is a glaring error: *A 600:1200Ω transformer would have a 1:2 transformation ratio*

Comment: Good catch on that. But otherwise I think it is a reasonably good basic article on inductor and transformer design, and contains information that may be helpful for answering the OP's question. This might be better for explaining impedance transformers: https://electronicsarea.com/impedance-matching-transformer/.